# How to configure LLVM to compile for wasm target without int64?

Tags: llvm, webassembly, compiler-options

Suppose I have an intermediate representation .ll file which uses, among others, types of int64. How can I instruct LLVM to compile this .ll file into wasm bytecode that uses int32 variables instead of int64?

Is this doable by appropriately setting the [data layout](https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#data-layout)?

Answer (score 0):

WebAssembly supports int64 natively so LLVM lowers its int64 type to WebAssembly's int64 type.  I don't think there is any support in llvm for lowering int64 in any other way.